# How to rebuild/reinstall dependencies of an up to date CPAN module?

Tags: perl, dependencies, cpan

I need to reinstall the dependencies of a CPAN module. Some dependencies which are usually installed are missing but the package itself is up to date to cpan.

So how can i still install the dependencies?

Comment: Yes i know the lib directory is messed up but its not my fault ;)

Answer (score 25):

Be forceful.

From `cpan` command-line application:

```
$ cpan -f -i Module::With::Dependencies
```

From `CPAN shell`:

```
cpan[1]> force install Module::With::Dependencies
```

Comment: That only reinstalls the module itself but not the missing dependencies. Where does cpan track which module is installed? Does it track this information at all?

Answer (score 4):

You might try installing [App::cpanminus](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/App-cpanminus), then use its `cpanm` command-line tool to install the module and its dependencies (try `cpanm --help` to get a list of the options).

(I also just discovered [App::pmuninstall](http://search.cpan.org/~xaicron/App-pmuninstall), which helped with a nasty case of refusal to update all of the files for a module by letting me uninstall the module first before installing the up-to-date version.)